# Getting value from one activity to another class

Tags: java, android, android-intent

can anyone guide me to the right direction, as the situation is 
have two classes calssA with Activity  while classB is simple java class

1.classA has a editbox where the user inputs some value.
2.classB has a method that computes the user input.

need to get the user input value from classA to classB.

a).cannot get it through passing intent as the other class does not have activity.
b).have tried getter setter method by creating a class thus,calling setter where the user inputs the detail.
   and calling the getter in another class.

Still the value is null, so what apparently is missing here.Any guidance to a example or brief explanation would be great.Thanks

Comment: have you checked the docs. There is sample with code snippets. http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

Comment: Yes,have read it through but by using intent it starts another activity.As I mentioned classB is just a simple java class with no activity.

Comment: You can use static variable in your first class and store that value which you want to send when you press next activity's button or image whatever. And then use that static variable over there..

Comment: @JaneWi.S then just pass the value to the constructor of class b.

Comment: Could you post some code, so we get an idea of what you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save the edittext value in SharedPreferences, thus making it available in all activity.
By doing this you can fetch the value in other activity without any hassle.

eg:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putString("edtTextValue", valueOfEditText);
editor.commit();
```

Further fetching the value in other activity like this,

```
preferences.getString("edtTextValue", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use your own customized class to store the data and use it any where you need.

### DataClass

```
public class Data {

       private String a,b;
   private static Data data= new Data( );

   /* A private Constructor prevents any other 
    * class from instantiating.
    */
   private Data (){ }

   /* Static 'instance' method */
   public static Data getInstance( ) {
      return data;
   }

       public String getA()
       {
          return this.a;
       }

       public String getB()
       {
          return this.b;
       }

       public void setA(String a)
       {
          this.a = a;
       }

       public String getB(String b)
       {
          this.b = b;
       }
  }
```

### In Activity

```
Data data = Data.getInstance()

data.setA("Stack");
data.setA("Overflow");
```

you can use this values in Java file like this

```
Data data = Data.getInstance()

System.out.println(data.getA());
System.out.println(data.getB());
```

Answer (score 1):

according to my knowledge here you have to use singleton class.

```
public class DataHolderClass {
private static DataHolderClass dataObject = null;

private DataHolderClass() {
    // left blank intentionally
}

public static DataHolderClass getInstance() {
    if (dataObject == null)
        dataObject = new DataHolderClass();
    return dataObject;
}

private String _ProductNames;

public String get_ProductNames() {
    return _ProductNames;
}

public void set_ProductNames(String _ProductNames) {
    this._ProductNames = _ProductNames;
}
}
```

to set data

```
DataHolderClass.DataHolderClass.set_ProductNames(your data variable);
```

to get data

```
DataHolderClass.DataHolderClass.get_ProductNames(your data variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your activity class create

```
public static String valueEntered;
valueEntered=mEdtTxt.getText().toString();
```

and in your java class where you want

```
String enteredValue=ClassA.valueEntered;
```