# How to access user input from an activity to another class?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, static, android-edittext

I have an activity called **`ParticleActivity`** in my `Android Studio` project.

```
public class ParticleActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "pso.algo.MESSAGE";
private ProgressDialog pd;
private double[] results = {-1.0, -1.0, -1.0};
EditText particles = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.particles);
EditText iterations = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.iterations);
static EditText solution;
public static double userSolution = Double.parseDouble(solution.getText().toString());
static EditText battery;
public static double batteryLevel = Double.parseDouble(battery.getText().toString());
```

The `userSolution` and `batteryLevel` are declared so that the user input in those fields can be accessed by another class, **`customUseCase`**.

```
public class CustomUseCase extends Test {

public ArrayList<Double> costData = MainActivity.costDATA; //costs that the user enters for each resource
public ArrayList<Double> costWlan = MainActivity.costWLAN;
public ArrayList<Double> costUtilities = MainActivity.costUTILITY;
public double batteryCost = ParticleActivity.batteryLevel; //battery cost user enters
public double userSolution = ParticleActivity.userSolution; //user's predicted solution
private int maxIter;
private int noParticles;
```

I know this isn't a good way of writing code as it says on `Android Studio` that I will get a memory leak because the `Android` components shouldn't be declared as static variables. But this is the only way (from my little knowledge of `Android`) that I can think off where I can access the user input from the `EditText` fields in `ParticleActivity` so that it can be used in my `customUseCase` class. Can someone give me a good way I can write this out? Thank you.

Comment: You problem seemed similar to this please check this link. [Get value from an activity to another class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23166016/7820465)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Intent` class and its `putExtra` method
see the docomentation here
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

example usage

```
Intent i = new Intent(ParticleActivity.this,CustomUseCase.class)
                     i.putExtra("myShow","one");
```

then on your CustomUseCase class

```
Intent i=getIntent();
String show=i.getStringExtra("myShow");
```

Comment: I did this, but when I try retrieve it in the customUseCase class, it doesn't recognize getIntent?

Comment: @AzIslam I have edited my answer for you if this answer your problem you can accept it as an answer

Comment: getIntent() doesn't work in my CustomUseCase class as it is not an activity, is there another way?